# What is YGPS and why does it have every permission that's in the book?

Tags: applications, security

I have a FairPhone One. From time to time I look in the system settings and the battery usage to see what is draining the battery. I've disabled anything I don't use, including a number of builtins from Google. I've also looked at other apps and if their permissions are in balance with what they're supposed to do. (Simple games should not have access to my phone calls.)

What is YGPS and why does it have the longest possible list of permissions? Can I safely disable it?

Answer (score 2):

YGPS, as far as I can discern (I don't own a FairPhone), is an app which lets you view what GPS satellites your phone is currently connected to. I'm guessing it probably provides the same kind of function here, and is likely draining your battery life because it's constantly making GPS calls in the background.

My guess is that, being a poorly developed app, the developers decided to call every permission possible to ensure they wouldn't run into any issues. It's likely only using the GPS function of the phone anyway, but considering you were going to anyway it's probably not a bad idea to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

It has beau coup permissions because it it a system app running in a phone/sms/gps/sim process that needs those permissions.Battery usage may be due to phone, sms, etc monitoring.

I prefer GPS Status app to view satellite array info, compass, battery temperature, voltage, etc.