# How to delete an app

Tags: applications, delete

I can't delete, or disable, the app YGPS,
on my Android tablet; and I didn't install it.

Comment: Related: [What is YGPS and why does it have every permission that's in the book?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/68873/44325)

Answer (score 0):

It's a preinstalled app(bloatware) so follow this guide and you should be able to remove it(NOTE:Requires rooting your phone which means voiding your warranty and beside rooting no way to remove them exists): https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-uninstall-preinstalled-android-apps#delete-preinstalled

Answer (score 0):

Dino Bajič is probably right, yet also there could be some app on Google Play that could allow you to disable or block existing apps. Also directly deleting that apps files from the device (after backing them up!) could help. (I never really tried it myself, so be careful)